# EAI_AGAIN error while installing yarn packages with Docker and VPN

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, yarnpkg, vpn

I am trying to run **yarn install** inside a docker container, and having this *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

ARG API_USER_TOKEN
ENV API_USER_TOKEN=$API_USER_TOKEN

WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN chown -R node:node /home/node
USER node

COPY package.json yarn.lock .npmrc ./

RUN yarn install

COPY nest-cli.json tsconfig.json tsconfig.build.json ./

EXPOSE 9000 50051

CMD ["yarn", "start:dev"]
```

All i get, is this error while fetching yarn packages:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/cron-parser: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com".
```

I'm connected to work *VPN* and working on Ubuntu, and i believe it's a *VPN* related issue. So far i tried this:

1. Copying *DNS adresses* from /etc/resolv.conf file to /etc/docker/daemon.json and restarting docker service.
2. Trying *openconnect* and *Cisco Anyconnect*.
3. Setting docker network to host instead of bridge.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score -1):

Please try to append for example Google DNS inside docker */etc/resolv.conf* like the following:

```
# ... previous DNS servers
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```